# JavaScript table library

Tags: library, javascript, html, table

I wrote a JavaScript program a few years ago that displays a large data table. I am currently using a thin wrapper around the basic HTML tag. This was never ideal, but it was easy to implement. As time has gone on, the amount of data the program displays has grown substantially which has caused the performance of the program to progressively deteriorate.

I am looking for a good table class to replace my current one.

I am currently looking at SlickGrid, but it doesn't appear to be able to allow variable row height (afaik). I need the class to be able to mimick the formatting behavior of the basic HTML table, but to be able to perform well with large amounts of data. I would also like to have the ability to do column resizing.

Comment: I am not familiar with it but check out [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), it may be what your looking for.

Comment: I think that you need to research first and then give us a list of features. For instance, you say “be able to perform well with large amounts of data”.  My first thought is that you might have a 5000,000 row table, but only be displaying, say, 25 lines at a time. So, a sliding window where the table only has 25 rows, but they are repopulated up & down with a scroll bar sounds like a good idea.  Are there any more features that you need? Click on column tittle to sort? Drag columns to rearrange? Export data? Two way data binding (use AngiularJS)?   Please think about that & help us to help you

Comment: Must this component be freely available for commerical use, do you have a budget in mind, or is it non-commerical?

Comment: Yet another "bumped to front page" where the OP has not logged in since two days after posting :-(

Answer (score 2):

## Vaadin Grid

Perhaps the most sophisticated data grid tool for web standard technologies you'll find is [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid).

Originally developed for the Vaadin Java-based server-side framework which uses [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) to automagically render the user interface in a web browser using standard web technologies, the Vaadin team has now made the *Vaadin Grid* tool available separately via [Web Components](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) and [Polymer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library)) technology.

This is cutting-edge stuff, and industry-leading. So there may be some changes along the way, and some speed-bumps as they innovate in this new delivery platform. But the Vaadin company has a long record of success in this field.

Comment: A good suggestion - plus it looks like it will work with AngularJs, for those who want free two way data binding https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-and-angularjs-happy-together

Comment: the the first link is now 404, but only because they have redesigned their web site. The grid can still be found at https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, fixed. FYI, on any Stack Exchange you are welcome to edit an Answer directly yourself to fix such problems, if you are so inclined.